# VB.Net Linq with datatables - select from one table what does not exist in the other

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I have two data on which I have applied the linq to select some lines :

```
csql = "select * from V_Vente where code_projet=" & ComProjet.GetColumnValue("code_projet") & " "
Dim tabVnt as Datatable = utilitaire.getDatatable(csql)

Dim query1 = tabVnt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(r) DirectCast(r("date"), Date) >= dtDu And DirectCast(r("date"), Date) <= dtAu)

Dim tabAnnule As DataTable = utilitaire.getDatatable("select  * from V_Reserv_Annule")
Dim query2 = From cust In tabAnnule.AsEnumerable() Where (cust.type = "définitif" Or cust.type = "Transfert") And cust.date_annule <= dtAu
```

now what i want is to select rows from "query1" where "Num_R" not exist in "query2".
The column "Num_r" exist in both datatable "tabVnt" and "tabAnnule"
I've tried this code but he doesn't work,please help me to find the error :

```
dim rows = from t1 in query1 .AsEnumerable() join t2 in query2.AsEnumerable() on t1.Field(Of String)("Num_r") equals t2.Field(Of String)("Num_r") Into tg
        From tcheck In tg.DefaultIfEmpty()
        Where tcheck = null
        Select t1()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution for my issus ,and i'd like to share it here with you :

```
Dim csql = "select * from V_Vente where code_projet=" & ComProjet.GetColumnValue("code_projet") & " "
Dim tabVnt As DataTable = utilitaire.getDatatable(csql) 

Dim query1 = tabVnt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(r) DirectCast(r("date"), Date) >= dt1 And DirectCast(r("date"), Date) <= dt2).ToList

Dim tabAnnule As DataTable = utilitaire.getDatatable("select  * from V_Reserv_Annule")

  bannedCCList = From c In tabAnnule.AsEnumerable() _
                 Where (c!type.Equals("définitif") = True Or c!type.Equals("Transfert") = True) And c!date_annule <= dt2
                 Select c.Field(Of String)("num_recu")

   Dim exceptData = (From c In query1.AsEnumerable() _
                    Where Not bannedCCList.Contains(c.Field(Of String)("num_recu")) _
                    ).ToList
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your code right, you can check if second table's `Num_r`s does not contain the table one `Num_r`:

```
Dim rows = t1.Where(x=> !t2.Select(y=> y.Num_r).Contains(x.Num_r));
```